# Access database every second using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, performance

I have a `JavaScript` script, that uses `Ajax` to call `PHP` page, the php page fetch the new updates from `MYSQL` database..

`Ajax` request is repeated every one second .

Does it a good practice to access database every second ? 
Is there any other suggestion to improve this operation ?

### edit

I want to make something like twitter real-time updates, each second I will retrieve only the new data, if there is no new data, nothing will return from database ( but still access the database every 1 sec)

Comment: Whether this is "good practice" is entirely application-dependent. How much data are you retrieving every second? Do you have a reasonably fast database server? Do you see any performance change when you use longer or shorter intervals? You will need to consider your requirements and benchmark the results on your own system to decide if it is a good idea.

Comment: Can you give more information on the purpose? Why every second? Why is caching not an option with forced updates? Maybe there is a way to optimize your approach.

Comment: ok thank. so there is no standard way :), I have to test and see

Comment: look into using [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) maybe??

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are **not** using `setInterval` but are using callbacks when your ajax call is successful or else you might have a backlog of calls that get stuck.

Also you might want to utilize some long-polling methods like websockets, comet, or server-sent-events.

Answer (score 2):

I would not design a dependency between my UI and my database directly.

It's probably reasonable (depending on the app needs) to have the UI call a web service once a second.  That web service can decide whether the correct strategy is to return a cached result or get new data from the database (if you have dozens of calls from dozens of browsers per second, you certainly don't want to call MySQL dozens of times in that one second.).

Having the UI call a web service and the web service interact with the database decouples the decisions "how often should the UI ask for more data?" from "how often should I check my database for an update?"

Answer (score 0):

It is never good practice to be pulling from a database repeatedly in such a short period of time, and I've never encountered a situation where it actually needed to be done. Is there a hard requirement to have updated information guaranteed to within the last second? If not, change the time between polling to once a minute, minimum. That alone will provide a major speed boost, and will reduce your server load significantly.

Alternatively, if you need up-to-date information whenever a user performs some action, just poll the database at the beginning of that action.

Comment: 'Never' here is used with the implicit context of, 'With the current technology available.' In addition, the use of any other word tends to make people think that their application is The Exception, instead of reevaluating what they're doing to try to find a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is better to use SJAX (Synchronous ) if you really have to make request in every second. This will help reduce backlog of calls. because it makes second request after it get the first response. for example:

```
    funftion get_data(){

                   if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url ,**false**);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
                            return xmlhttp.responseText;
                     }
```

use false in open() method to make it synchronized